# Is there any old style keyboard (numpad style) available for Android?

Tags: keyboard

I have a smaller screen Android Phone (LG Optimus One P500).

**Does anyone know whether there is a keyboard available for Android phones that has an "old phone" style?** Like a numpad style? Here's an image example:

[image: Numpad style keyboard]

The reason I'm asking for this style of keyboard is:

1. This style uses only 12 buttons. So the buttons are large and very spaced out. You can click on them easily without having to strain your eyes too much.
2. You can quickly keep clicking away without having to spell out each word because the dictionary will take care of that. So "moon" becomes 4 clicks on the numpad 6. How fast is that?

I sure personally feel that lots of people are used to this kind of keyboard layout (from the times before Android became so popular). I don't understand why I can't find keyboards with this kind of a simple layout but I would be very grateful if someone could help me find an app like this.

**Edit:** Forgot to mention. I'm not looking for paid apps right now but would consider it if they have a trial.

Comment: You're not likely to find a free app that lets you tap each key once, using a dictionary. This feature is called T9 and is patented, so even an open-source project would have to pay a large license fee to offer it.

Comment: Buttons Keypad is better than a single screen pad for olden style people and I also like Buttons Pad Phone, instead of single screen.

Answer (score 2):

Well...Look for a keyboard that has a T9 layout.

As an example, I use Smart Keyboard Pro (which is a paid app, but [a trial](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.cdeguet.smartkeyboardtrial) is available) and you can choose from the full, T9 and compact modes for portrait as well as landscape orientation. There are tons of other customizable options and considering that a keyboard that one is comfortable with, is what allows one to at their productive best, I opted to buy the full version.

[image: T9 Style Smart Keyboard]  [image: Smart Keybd Compact Layout]

Answer (score 1):

It's not the T9 style that you're looking for, but I use the [MessagEase](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.exideas.mekb) keyboard. Here's a sample:

[image]

As you can see, it certainly has large buttons. It's also far more capable than any other keyboard I've run across. From the keyboard shown, you can enter lowercase letters, uppercase letters, numbers, symbols, cursor movement commands, and more. Some are entered with a single tap, but most are entered with a simple gesture, such as a swipe or circle.

It also features word completion, which you can see in the screenshot, but I rarely use it, since I find my typing speed is fast enough not to bother with it unless I'm typing a really long word. The learning curve is steep, but worth the effort, in my opinion.

(In case anyone is wondering, I have no association with the development of MessagEase, I'm just a satisfied user.)

Answer (score 1):

Try [Multiling keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.klye.ime.latin&hl=en). It's free, it supports multiple languages, it have two numeric layout for you to choose from.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try GO SMS Pro. It lets you select between 2 different layouts.

[image]